# Python - Loop printing too many times when reading from an imported file

Tags: python, list, loops

Im writing a program to output a table that calculates pay roll.
it is reading from an imported file.

The file I'm using to test contains:

- Barb,Moran,51,12.85
- Joy,Rinehimer,30,9.35
- Joe,Bellucci,45,9.55
- Dave,Flaim,37,17.70

The idea here was to take each line and split it by the , and then go through position by position to print what I need to.
Here is the portion of my code that I think contains the issue:

```
def getFile():
    filename = input("Please enter the employee file name: ")
    print()
    infile = open(filename, "r")
    return infile

def outputs(infile):
    paylist = []
    count = 0

    for lines in infile:
        individual = lines.split(",")
        for pos in individual:
            first = ("{0:7}".format (individual[0]))
            print(first, end = "")

            last = ("{0:12}".format(individual[1]))
            print(last, end = "")

            hours = ("{0:6}".format(individual[2]))
            print(hours, end = "")

            wage = ("{0:6}".format(individual[3]))
            print ("$",wage, end = "")
```

When I run it, it outputs all of the correct values but 4 times over

Comment: `for pos in individual:` Remove that.

Comment: great, that worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop of `outputs()` is the culprit. Remove it.

```
def outputs(infile):
    paylist = []
    count = 0
    for lines in infile:
        individual = lines.split(",")
        first = ("{0:7}".format (individual[0]))
        print(first, end = "")

        last = ("{0:12}".format(individual[1]))
        print(last, end = "")

        hours = ("{0:6}".format(individual[2]))
        print(hours, end = "")

        wage = ("{0:6}".format(individual[3]))
        print ("$",wage, end = "")
```